# "core_user_get_users_by_field" function not returning any values in Moodle API and PHP

Tags: php, moodle-api

URL: [https://www.mywebsite.com/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=2727a8f23c07682dcac1b5cfc6871637&wsfunction=core_user_get_users_by_field&moodlewsrestformat=json&&criteria[0][key]=email&criteria[0][value]=xxx@gmail.com](https://www.mywebsite.com/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=2727a8f23c07682dcac1b5cfc6871637&wsfunction=core_user_get_users_by_field&moodlewsrestformat=json&&criteria%5B0%5D%5Bkey%5D=email&criteria%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=xxx@gmail.com)

This is the error displaying.

```
{"exception":"invalid_parameter_exception","errorcode":"invalidparameter","message":"Invalid parameter value detected","debuginfo":"Missing required key in single structure: field"}
```

Someone please help me in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the parameter field instead of the key.

Remove the criteria from end of URL and add `&field=email&values[]=xxx@gmail.com`

> [https://www.mywebsite.com/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=2727a8f23c07682dcac1b5cfc6871637&wsfunction=core_user_get_users_by_field&moodlewsrestformat=json&field=email&values[]=xxx@gmail.com](https://www.mywebsite.com/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=2727a8f23c07682dcac1b5cfc6871637&wsfunction=core_user_get_users_by_field&moodlewsrestformat=json&field=email&values%5B%5D=xxx@gmail.com)

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. It amazes me how badly documented all the API calls are.